# Simple fraction definition in Scilab but the answer is wrong

Tags: fractions, scilab

I have the following function f(x)=1/(x^5+1) like in [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ns3k-Lz7qWU), but when I try to implement it in Scilab, I get the wrong answers:

```
-->deff('y=f(x)','y=1/(1+(x.^5))')

-->x=0:.5:3
 x  =

    0.    0.5    1.    1.5    2.    2.5    3.  

-->w=f(x)
 w  =

    0.0000142  
    0.0000146  
    0.0000284  
    0.0001220  
    0.0004685  
    0.0014006  
    0.0034640
```

The `w` vector should have the following values:

```
1
0.96969697
0.5
0.116363636
0.03030303
0.010136205
0.004098361
```

What I have made wrong? I suppose it is because of the fraction.

Answer (score 0):

Defining the function like this :

```
-->deff('y=f(x)','y=ones(x)./(1+(x.^5))')
```

Will give the expected result :

```
-->f(0:.5:3)
 ans  =

    1.    0.9696970    0.5    0.1163636    0.0303030    0.0101362    0.0040984
```